# libvirt qemu cannot access image inside my home directory, even as root?

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I have problem getting my VM running via libvirt. Here is my setup:

- I put my qcow2 image and domain XML (named `win7.xml`) under `$HOME/vm`,
  with all files and directories using my user, my group, and permission bits `0644`.
- I uncommented `user = "root"`, `group = "root"` and `dynamic_ownership = 1`
  lines in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`, expecting `qemu-system-x86_64` will run
  as root, therefore having full access to the dirs and files under `$HOME/vm`.

However, invocation of `virsh create win7.xml` as root was failed:

```
error: Failed to create domain from win7.xml
error: internal error: early end of file from monitor, possible problem: 2016-10-01T03:36:02.049418Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/home/naitree/vm/win7/win7.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0: Could not open '/home/naitree/vm/win7/win7.qcow2': Permission denied
```

The following error was logged in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/win7.log`:

```
2016-10-01T03:36:02.049418Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/home/naitree/vm/win7/win7.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0: Could not open '/home/naitree/vm/win7/win7.qcow2': Permission denied
2016-10-01 03:36:02.080+0000: shutting down
```

It looks like qemu failed to access my VM disk file. But why? Didn't `qemu-system-x86_64`
run as root? What should be done to make sure libvirt-qemu able to access the disk image
residing in `$HOME` directory?

Additional version informations:

- libvirt, virsh version: 1.3.3.2
- QEMU version: QEMU emulator version 2.6.1 (qemu-2.6.1-1.fc24)
- distro: Fedora 24
- kernel: 4.7.4-200.fc24.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely being blocked by Selinux, check your /var/log/audit.log